# partial derivatives and gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[image]

For c）,can anyone provide some hints? I can only think of showing the cross product equals 0 but don't know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint :

- What is the explicit function of  $x(\phi, \theta)$ ? $y(\phi, \theta)$ ? $z(\phi, \theta)$ ?
- Compute $\partial_\theta F=(\partial_\theta x, \partial_\theta y, \partial_\theta z)$, and  $\partial_\phi F=(\partial_\phi x, \partial_\phi y, \partial_\phi z)$
- Compute $\partial_\theta F \times \partial_\phi F $
- What is $\nabla(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ in terms of $(x,y,z)$ ? Replace with $(x(\phi, \theta), y(\phi, \theta), z(\phi, \theta))$
- Can you notice the relation of proportionality ? If not compute the cross product $(\partial_\theta F \times \partial_\phi F ) \times \nabla(x^2+y^2+z^2)$